# The user keep geting invalid session when trying to upload files

Tags: attachment, files

We enabled option on Salesforce Files Setting:

> Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded
>   as Salesforce Files, not as attachments .

After that, user keep getting error below when they trying to upload files:

> "The action you performed was invalid for your session.Please refresh
>   your page and try again."

It works fine after we opt out the option.Have anyone face the issue before?How you solve it because we plan to move to Salesforce Files instead of old Attachment.

Comment: Is it on a vf page or a standard button ?

Comment: standard button

Comment: check the ans if it helps

Comment: Is chatter enabled and adding feed tracking help you?

Comment: I will check with the user, hopefully the Answer above helps the problem.I will come back once I get the reply.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava the chatter and feedtracking is already enabled but the issue still happening.